# Expressjs: Run method when button gets pressed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, listener

I want to run a function on my node server if a buttons on my website gets pressed:

What I have until yet:
**Index.html** (For simplicity I didn't add the whole website)

```
<button id="tv">tv</button>
```

**Client.js (Client side)**

```
const tv = document.getElementById('tv');
volup.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  fetch('/tv', {method: 'POST'})
});
```

**Index.js (Server side)** (Client.js & Index.html are located in the "public" folder

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(80, function () {
   console.log('Webserver running!');
});
app.post('/tv', (req, res) => {
  console.log('it works');
})
```

Does my solution make sense or is there a  better one. Until yet it is working but after a few presses on the button the log on server side isn't coming anymore.

I appreciate any advice :)

Comment: You are using on your server method `app.get` but the buttons tries to fire method "post".

Comment: Edit: It should be 'app.post'. I'm very sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending a response from your post, so you're accumulating outstanding requests.

Try making your post handler send a response, for example:

```
app.post('/tv', (req, res) => {
    console.log('it works');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: that was the problem. Now it works. Thank you very much!